# Why doesn't style="@android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" cause error?

Tags: android

I think the following code will cause error, I think the Android system lib doesn't exist a style named listSeparatortextViewStyle in styles.xml.
But the code doesn't cause error, why?

```
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    style="@android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"  
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't show a error because the actually is a listSeparatorTextViewStyle.
Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listSeparatorTextViewStyle). Have you even tried to look this up?